# Adding Form Fields Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this function to add form labels and fields to a given container:

```
function addFormField(fieldType, fieldLabel, fieldId){
        var container = document.querySelector("formContainer");
        // form field label
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.for = fieldId;
        label.innerHTML = fieldLabel;
        // form field
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = fieldType;
        input.id = fieldId;
        input.name = fieldId;
        // add in label, field, and break to container
        container.appendChild(label);
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
```

where a function call would look like

```
addFormField('text', 'Email Address', 'email');
```

and I am given this error message when running the exact same call as above

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name.
```

I could not find an answer elsewhere online, but I apologize if this issue is common knowledge. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Thanks for pointing that out! I made that error while copying over the call from my code so I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: No problem, though obviously I’ve removed the now-obsolete comment. Incidentally, this is unlikely to related to your problem, but `label.for` should be [`label.htmlFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/htmlFor). Are you sure that’s an exact copy of your code? I can’t see any reason that `document.createElement()` would fail to run in what you’ve posted.

Comment: `document.querySelector("formContainer")` tries to select a tag. Fixing that and `label.htmlFor` issue David mentioned, your code works as it is.

Comment: @Teemu even with `document.querySelector("#formContainer");`, I still get the same error. It's possible I'm misinterpreting your comment since I am fairly new to javascript but based on my knowledge that should be correct?

Comment: Without your relevant (*[mcve]*) html we can’t say what the selector should be, unfortunately.

Comment: [No](https://jsfiddle.net/auhLf4rb/)..? The error message suggests that there's an empty string in the argument of `document.createElement(...)`, but in your example code all the arguments are correctly populated.

Comment: @Teemu super weird. With all of my code together I still get that error, however when I isolate that part I do not. Without sharing all my code, is there anything I should be looking out for that would cause this to conflict? I triple checked that my div has the correct class and even copied in the version that you linked. Since the code works on its own and then does not when I add it all together, it seems that conflicting code is the only other possible reason.

Comment: Is the line number in the error message pointing to a line which occurs in your example code? Maybe in your real code you've a variable as an argument, and that variable happens to keep the empty string ..?